# Mixed C++ and Fortran Linking Issue

Tags: c++, linker, fortran, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have done some searching online but I cannot find out how to compile a simple C++ and Fortran code from linux. I need to get complex with it, but I just need to know how to start with a simple example.

My C++ code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern int Add( int *, int * );
extern int Multiply( int *, int * );

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;  
    cout << "Enter 2 values: ";
    cin >> a >> b;

    c = Add(&a,&b);
    cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
    c = Multiply(&a,&b);
    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My Fortran Code is this:

```
integer function Add(a,b)
    integer a,b
    Add = a+b
    return
end


integer function Multiply(a,b)
    integer a,b
    Multiply = a*b
    return
end
```

I am using `ifort` to compile my Fortran code and g++ for C++ code. I have tried this terminal command:

```
$ ifort -c Program.f90
$ g++ -o Main.cpp Program.o
```

But the error I am getting says "linker input file unused because linking not done."
I am not sure how to link the two together. If someone could please help me out I would greatly appreciate it!

PS - I have tried adding `-lg2c` at the end of my compilation line, and it is not recognized.

Comment: you `g++` seems wrong, should be `g++ -o Program.o Main.cpp

Comment: @ZacWrangler It should not, because the C++ Program.o would overwrite previously built Fortran Program.o. Rather, have different object file names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are few issues here that don't let names of the objects match. First, specify in the C++ code that the external functions have the C signature:

In test.cpp:

```
extern "C" int Add( int *, int * );
extern "C" int Multiply( int *, int * );
```

See [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c) for more details.

In your Fortran code, make the interface explicit by placing procedures in the module, and use `iso_c_binding` to let Fortran objects appear as valid C objects. Notice that we can explicitly specify the names of the objects that the C or C++ programs will see through the `bind` keyword:

test_f.f90:

```
module mymod
use iso_c_binding
implicit none

contains

integer(kind=c_int) function Add(a,b) bind(c,name='Add')
    integer(kind=c_int) :: a,b
    Add = a+b
end function

integer(kind=c_int) function Multiply(a,b) bind(c,name='Multiply')
    integer(kind=c_int) :: a,b
    Multiply = a*b
end function

endmodule mymod
```

Compile (don't mind me using the Intel suite, my g++ & gfortran are very old):

```
$ ifort -c test_f.f90 
$ icpc -c test.cpp
```

Link:

```
$ icpc test_f.o test.o
```

Executing `a.out` should now work as expected.

Comment: Note the `use iso_c_binding` statement is superfluous for the code as presented - no entities from that module are being accessed.

Comment: @IanH Ah I didn't realize that. I edited the code to remove redundancy :).

Comment: This is a lot better than dealing with those crazy no-underscores compiler flags!